# Type-level sets in Haskell / Agda

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I've seen that in the latest versions of GHC there's support for type-level lists. However, I need to work with type-level sets for an application, and would like to implement a type-level set library based on type-level lists. But I don't know where to start :(

Is there any library supporting type-level sets in Haskell?

Comment: Well the various extensible record libraries give you set-ish operations (union, checking if a label is in the record), even if the implementation isn't a tree like Data.Set. Check out the list <http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Extensible_record#Libraries_on_hackage>, or other bits on that page.

Comment: There is now [a library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-sets) that provides this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HSet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/latest/doc/html/Data-HList-HListPrelude.html#t%3aHSet) property for [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/latest/doc/html/Data-HList-HListPrelude.html#t%3aHList)'s from [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.HList

class (HList l, HSet l) => ThisIsSet l where
  -- Here we have @l@ which is @HList@ _and_ @HSet@.
  test :: l

-- This is ok:

instance ThisIsSet HNil where
  test = hNil

-- And this:

instance ThisIsSet (HCons HZero HNil) where
  test = hCons hZero hNil

-- And this (HZero != HSucc HZero):

instance ThisIsSet (HCons HZero (HCons (HSucc HZero) HNil)) where
  test = hCons hZero (hCons (hSucc hZero) hNil)

-- This is an error since HSucc HZero == HSucc HZero:

instance ThisIsSet (HCons (HSucc HZero) (HCons (HSucc HZero) HNil)) where
  test = hCons (hSucc hZero) (hCons (hSucc hZero) hNil)
```

for working with other types you need to write [HEq](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/latest/doc/html/Data-HList-FakePrelude.html#t%3aHEq) instances for them.